# Types of Investment Funds : Mutual Funds, ETF, SICAV, FCP, UCITS

Tags: mutual-funds, hedge-funds

I know this could be a very basic topic but I would just want to understand the different types of funds.

From my understanding the ones listed in the title : mutual funds, FCP, ETF, SICAV, etc.. are different types of funds in the way the are managed and the organization on the funds.

On the other hand, these different types of funds can have another type based on the underlying investments : stock funds, bond funds, real state funds, etc...

Is this assumption correct? Do you have any information to list all the types of funds of the first typology and a basic description for each? I just see comparisons between ETF vs SICAV and so on, but not a full view of all types of funds.

Thanks a lot in advance,

Kat